# How can I use delayed job in a call back function in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, delayed-job

I'm using delayed_job gem.

I want to call a method using a callback as follows

after_update :get_score

How can I use delay_job for this so that the get_score method is run in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with `delayed_job`, but judging from its docs, this should work.

```
after_update :obtain_score

def get_score
   # code
end

private
def obtain_score
  delay.get_score
end
```

Comment: Hi, Yes that kinda what I did I was just thinking there would be a way to do it all in one shot. Guess not

Answer (score 3):

How about this? Works for me.

```
after_update :get_score

private
def get_score
  # code
end
handle_asynchronously :get_score
```